# Issue while sending email notification via shiny dashbaord

Tags: r, shiny

I am using mailR package to send email on click of a button on my shiny package. Here is what I am doing

```
observeEvent(input$sampleButton,{
send.mail(from="sample@test.com",
          to="sample@test.com",
          subject="test@sample.com",
          smtp=list(host.name = '1.1.1.1',port=25),
          autheticate = FALSE,
          send=TRUE)
})
```

Although the mail goes through, I get the following error :

```
error in as.character.default(text): no method for coercing this s4 class to vector
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to=` argument is expecting a character vector, try defining the recipients before calling the `send.mail` function like this..

From the function information page..

```
observeEvent(input$sampleButton,{
 recipients <- c("sample@test.com")
 send.mail(from="sample@test.com",
          to=recipients,
          subject="test@sample.com",
          smtp=list(host.name = '1.1.1.1',port=25),
          autheticate = FALSE,
          send=TRUE)
})
```

Comment: hello,@Chabo, what if the recipients is dynamically changing? For instance, there are multiple recipients, they all want the email (not the same time). How to define the to= ?